# JQuery. Remove existing handlers and call them on my own

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

I have child and parent elements that are retrieved by jquery selectors.

I listen to events that are bubbled from child to parent.

Somebody added a handler that prevents bubbling (and I can do nothing about this).

Thus I am interested to remove this handler and call it on my own after the event is bubbled and handled by me taking care of `this` context in order to keep the existing code workable.

How can I do that?

Thank you in advance!

Demo:

```js
$("#child").click(function(event) {
    alert("I am a child!");
  event.stopPropagation();  
})


$(document, "#parent").on("click", function() {
  alert("parent!");
})
```

```css
#parent  {
  padding: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #f00;
}

#child {  
  height: 100%;
  background: #0f0;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="parent">
  <div id="child">
  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How is the other event handler defined? Can you please show some example that reproduces your problem?

Comment: Please, take a look my snippet

Answer (score 0):

Use [.unbind()](https://api.jquery.com/unbind/) as `$( "#child").unbind( "click" );` to unbind click attached to child ,

then do what ever you want to attach new click etcc ..

see below snippet :

```js
$(function() {

  $("#child").click(function(event) {
    alert("I am a child!");
    event.stopPropagation();
  })

  $("#child").unbind("click");

  $(document, "#parent").on("click", function(e) {
    alert("click on " + e.target.id)
  })

});
```

```css
#parent {
  padding: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #f00;
}

#child {
  height: 100%;
  background: #0f0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="parent">
  <div id="child">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I don't want to just remove and forget about the previous child handler. I want to call the previous handler after my work is done inside my "on"-assigned function

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .off() method to disable event listener.

https://api.jquery.com/off/

Comment: Thank you, but I don't want to just remove and forget about the previous child handler. I want to call the previous handler after my work is done inside my "on"-assigned function